# How to use \usepackage{bera} in tex4ht? It does not like the `f` letter?

Tags: fonts, tex4ht

I like the font provided by `\usepackage{bera}`. But when using this in tex4ht, it seems to drop some letters from some words for some reason. In this example, it does not like the `f` letters and removes them from all words.

Is it possible to make this work in tex4ht? Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%

\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
term by term differentiation is justified here
\end{document}
```

`lualatex foo.tex` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But  `make4ht -u foo.tex` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also tried

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%

\usepackage{bera}
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\else 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi 

\begin{document}
term by term differentiation is justified here
\end{document}
```

But same result.

Does one need a trick to make this work in tex4ht, or is it simply not supported?

Using texlive 2017 on Linux. I use only `lualatex` to compile to PDF and use `make4ht -u` to compile to HTML.  The PDF is fine, the problem is in the HTML only.

**Update**

Added log file

```
drop_letter>cat foo.tex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}%

\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
term by term differentiation is justified here
\end{document}

drop_letter>ls -lrt *.htf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me 44 Feb 15 11:51 fveb8r.htf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me 46 Feb 15 11:52 fvero8r.htf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me  6 Feb 15 11:53 fver8t.htf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me 42 Feb 15 11:55 fveb8t.htf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me 44 Feb 15 11:56 fvero8t.htf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me 10 Feb 15 18:42 fver8r.htf

drop_letter>cat  fver8r.htf
.pcrro8r

drop_letter>which make4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/make4ht/make4ht
```

Screen log

```
drop_letter>make4ht  foo.tex
.....
Output written on foo.dvi (1 page, 9652 bytes).
....
Transcript written on foo.log.
Make4ht: tex4ht  "foo.dvi"
----------------------------
tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 kpathsea)
tex4ht foo.dvi 
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/iso8859/1/charset/unicode.4hf)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/bera/fver8t.tfm)
(fver8t.htf)
.lm-ec--- error --- Improper file `fver8t.htf'
Make4ht: Fatal error. Command tex4ht returned exit code 256
drop_letter>
```

Log file

```
drop_letter>cat foo.log
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=latex 2017.11.10)  15 FEB 2018 18:47
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCo
de"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.
{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\
documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname
 tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{
\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode xhtml,.a.b.c.\input foo.tex

(./foo.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty
version 2016-07-18-16:08
Package: tex4ht 
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for _ at preamble, use the command line option `early_'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for ^ at preamble, use the command line option `early^'
--------------------------------------
\tmp:toks=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/bera.sty
Package: bera 2004/01/31 (WaS)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 79.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 349.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 350.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 351.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 352.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 353.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 354.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 355.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 356.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 357.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 358.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 359.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 360.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 361.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 362.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 363.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 364.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 365.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 366.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 367.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 368.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 369.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 370.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 371.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 372.

Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 373.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 374.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 375.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 376.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 377.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 378.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 379.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 380.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 381.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 382.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 383.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 384.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 385.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 386.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 387.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 388.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 389.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 390.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 391.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 392.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 393.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 394.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 395.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 396.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 397.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 398.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 399.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 400.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 401.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 402.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 403.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 404.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 405.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 406.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 407.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 408.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 409.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/beraserif.sty
Package: beraserif 2004/01/30 (WaS)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+fve on input line 30.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/t1fve.fd
File: t1fve.fd 2004/09/07 scalable font definitions for T1/fve.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/fve/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.85492pt on input line 30.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/berasans.sty
Package: berasans 2004/01/30 (WaS)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/beramono.sty
Package: beramono 2004/01/31 (WaS)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.4ht
version 2017-05-09-09:21
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for additional information, use the command line option `info'
--------------------------------------

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty
version 2016-07-18-16:08

--- needs --- tex4ht foo ---
\tmp:cnt=\count87
\openout15 = `foo.tmp'.

(./foo.tmp)
\tmp:dim=\skip43
 (./foo.xref)
\:refout=\write3
\openout3 = `foo.xref'.


(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2017-10-26-14:53
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- to remove the <?xml version=...?> processing instruction use the c
ommand line option `no-VERSION'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- to remove the DOCTYPE declaration use the command line option `no-
DOCTYPE'
--------------------------------------
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2017-03-30-16:04
)
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for marking of the base font, use the command line option `fonts+'

--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for non active _, use the command line option `no_'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for _ of catcode 13, use the command line option `_13'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for non active ^, use the command line option `no^'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for ^ of catcode 13, use the command line option `^13'
--------------------------------------

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2017-10-26-14:53
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for alternative charset, use the command line option `charset=...'

--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- to ignore CSS font decoration, use the `NoFonts' command line opti
on
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for jpg bitmaps of pictures, use the `jpg' command line option. (C
haracter bitmaps are controled only by `g' records of tex4ht.env and `-g' switc
hes of tex4ht.c) 
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for gif bitmaps of pictures, use the `gif' command line option. (C
haracter bitmaps are controled only by `g' records of tex4ht.env and `-g' switc
hes of tex4ht.c) 
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for content and toc in 2 frames, use the command line option `fram
es'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for content, toc, and footnotes in 3 frames, use the command line 
option `frames-fn'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for file extension name xht, use the command line option `xht'
--------------------------------------
TeX4ht package options: xhtml,html
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- To print a timestamp, use the command line option timestamp
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- to ignore CSS code, use the command line option `-css
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for inline CSS code, use the command line option `css-in'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for pop ups on mouse over, use the command line option `mouseover'

--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for addressing images in a subdirectory, use the command line opti
on `imgdir:.../'
--------------------------------------
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2017-03-30-16:04
)
\:tokwrite=\toks16
\:tokpage=\toks17
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for back links to toc, use the command line option `sections+'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for linear crosslinks of pages, use the command line option `next'

--------------------------------------
\openout15 = `foo.4ct'.

\:tocout=\write4
\openout4 = `foo.4tc'.


(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2017-10-26-14:53
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2017-03-30-16:04
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/latex.4ht
version 2017-01-24-15:21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \_ on input line 168.
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for links into captions, instead of float heads, use the command l
ine option `refcaption'
--------------------------------------

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2017-10-26-14:53
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- For mini tocs immediately aftter the header use the command line o
ption `minitoc<'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for enumerated list elements with valued data, use the command lin
e option `enumerate+'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for enumerated list elements li's with value attributes, use the c
ommand line option `enumerate-'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for CSS2 code, use the command line option `css2'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for pictorial tabular, use the command line option `pic-tabular'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for bitmap fbox'es, use the command line option `pic-fbox'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for bitmap framebox'es, use the command line option `pic-framebox'

--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for inline footnotes use command line option `fn-in'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for tracing of latex font commands, use the command line option `f
onts'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for width specifications of tabular p entries, use the `p-width' c
ommand line option or a configuration similar to \Configure{HColWidth}{\HCode{ 
style="width:\HColWidth"}}
--------------------------------------
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2017-03-30-16:04
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for pictorial eqnarray, use the command line option `pic-eqnarray'

--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for pictorial array, use the command line option `pic-array'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for pictorial $...$ environments, use the command line option `pic
-m' (not recommended!!)
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for pictorial $...$ and $$...$$ environments with latex alt, use t
he command line option `pic-m+' (not safe!!)
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for pictorial array, use the command line option `pic-array'
--------------------------------------
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/fontmath.4ht
version 2009-05-21-09:32

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2017-10-26-14:53
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2017-03-30-16:04
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/article.4ht
version 2009-05-21-09:32

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2017-10-26-14:53
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for automatic sectioning pagination, use the command line option `
1', `2', `3', '4', '5', '6', or '7'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for files named derived from section titles, use the command line 
option `sec-filename'
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
--- Note --- for i-columns index, use the command line option `index=i' (e.g., 
index=2)
--------------------------------------
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2017-03-30-16:04
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2017-10-26-14:53
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2017-03-30-16:04
))
(./foo.aux)
\openout1 = `foo.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 6.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
--- file foo.css ---

[1

] (./foo.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4199 strings out of 492986
 46895 string characters out of 8882611
 222098 words of memory out of 8000000
 7751 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6585 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 33i,4n,30p,638b,209s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,30000000b,80000s

Output written on foo.dvi (1 page, 9652 bytes).
drop_letter>
```

Comment: Looks like a very odd mixture. Why are you using unicode/lualatex with a T1-encoded font?

Comment: No I meant your comment "lualatex foo.tex". Your example is not a sensible lualatex document.  Your actually problem (which is not the f itself but the f-ligatures ff and fi) is probably due to the warning `Couldn't find font `fver8t.htf'` but I don't have the time to look now.

Comment: If you want to see a problem, insert  `Grüße` in your document. (This is not related to bera but to \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}). bera is a bitstream vera clone. With lualatex you would use something like `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Bitstream Vera Serif}`.

Comment: Then get the font, or use dejavu which imho is an extension. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Vera. And sorry a "font not found" message is not so difficult to understand.

Comment: It is necessary to add support files for these fonts.

Comment: The font is installed with TeX Live in a format suitable for use with pdfTeX or TeX. Specifically, `bera` provides virtual fonts in suitable font encodings which use type1 postscript fonts. It does not supply an opentype or truetype version. Does `luaotfload` really need to use quite so many exclamation marks to make its point?

Comment: what is in the `fver8t.htf` file? It seems to be corrupted. try to add blank line at the end of the file. doesn't it contain Windows newlines?

Comment: @michal.h21 You are right. I added extra CR at end, and now the error went away. I did not know I needed to do this. I created these files from what you had there. But it works now.  Where should these 6 files be located on the system so that they can be seen automatically? I do not want to copy them to each folder. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser stackexchange don't display the lines at the end, I think I had this issue in the past. You can save them to `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/adobe/bera`. But I updated tex4ht sources, so they should be included in TL soon.

Comment: @michal.h21 OK, thank you. I will wait for your TL updates then and do update then for the sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no support files for `Bera` fonts in `tex4ht`, so special characters that may be missing, as in your case the `ff` and `fi` ligatures. You can add the following files to the directory with your document:

fveb8r.htf:

```
.pcrro8r
htfcss: fveb8r  font-weight: bold;
```

fvero8r.htf:

```
.pcrro8r
htfcss: fvero8r  font-style: italic;
```

fver8r.htf:

```
.pcrro8r
```

fver8t.htf:

```
.lm-ec
```

fveb8t.htf:

```
.lm-ec
htfcss: fveb8t  font-weight: bold;
```

fvero8t.htf:

```
.lm-ec
htfcss: fvero8t  font-style: italic;
```

These files support italic and bold variants. You can also use `LuaTeX` as compiler for `make4ht` using the `-l` option.

The result seems to be correct:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I am not able to get it to work. I get error `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/bera/fver8r.tfm)
(fver8r.htf)
.pcrro8r--- error --- Improper file `fver8r.htf'
Make4ht: Fatal error. Command tex4ht returned exit code 256
` may be you used different options to compile with make4ht. I tried `make4ht foo.tex` where `foo.tex` is the file I posted at top of my question. I have all the 6 files as you show in same folder.

Comment: Do you recommend a location to put these 6 files in to use them from different places so I do not have to copy them to each folder?

Comment: @Nasser it is strange. can you post the full log file around these errors?